# how to test iPhone 5S apps on simulator in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, simulator

I have app which i have built for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 it works on both iPhone 4 and iPhone 5C but it does not work on iPhone 5S. On iPhone 5S it does not show some of button at bottom of screen which is being shown fine in iPhone 5C and iPhone. Is there any way to resolve this issue. As my app does not show some images on iPhone 5S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real way to try an app just for a device. Although in the iPhone 5s case, you can ask for the 64-bits simulator. It only works on iOS7+.

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The iOS 8 dev tools include device-specific simulators. They basically just switch between permutations of 64-bit, 32-bit, and different screen sizes.